# Convert List[(String,String)] to Map[String, Map[String,String]]

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

Let's say I have below List[(String, String)]:

```
List((recap_items[4].invoice_items[0].id,6),
(recap_items[4].invoice_items[1].id,7),
(recap_items[4].invoice_items[1].qty,1),
(recap_items[4].invoice_items[0].qty,1), 
(recap_items[4].invoice_items[1].sur_key,19), 
(recap_items[4].invoice_items[0].sur_key,17))
```

How could I convert that List into below Map?

```
Map(
recap_items[4].invoice_items[0] -> Map(id -> 6, qty -> 1, sur_key -> 17),
recap_items[4].invoice_items[1] -> Map(id -> 7, qty -> 1, sur_key -> 19)
)
```

Or is there any better representation to kinda group that List ?

**EDIT**

```
case class Recap(recap_id: String, recap_date: Date, submitted_id:String, edited_id: String, recap_items: List[Recap_items])

case class Recap_items(product_name: String, product_id: String, qty: Int, unit_name: String, unit_multiplier: Int, sys_qty: Int, invoice_items: List[Invoice_items])

case class Invoice_items(sur_key: Long, id: Long, qty: Int)
```

**CURRENT APPROACH**

Below is my current approach which gives me Map[String, List[String]]:

code:

```
flash.data.filterKeys(_.startsWith("recap_items["+i+"].invoice_items")).toList.sortBy(x => x._1).map{
            x => (x._1.split("""\.""").toList(1), x._2)
        }.groupBy(_._1).mapValues{
            x => x.map( v => v._2)
        }
```

output:

```
Map(invoice_items[1] -> List(7, 1, 19), 
invoice_items[0] -> List(6, 1, 17))
```

Any clue how to improve this code?

Comment: Can you post the class definition of the `invoice_items`?

Comment: mmm, what exactly means `Map(id -> 6, qty -> 1, sur_key -> 17)` for you? Are `id` and `qty` strings or field names directly or something else in that expression? What is the motivation of that conversion, to see if there's a more suitable option?

Comment: What have you tried? Once you've split the string, groupBy seems to do most of what you want.

Comment: kaktusito : id, qty and sur_key are field names, another option is to use Map[String, List[String]] but still I don't know how to group it.

Paul : Well, I don't know how to group it by that attributes. So, that's my main problem..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you want to convert everything into string (I mean, recap_items[4].invoice_items[1] instead of the actual item name).

If your input is a `Recap` object then you can just do:

```
val recap: Recap = ...
val map: Map[String, Map[String, String]] =
  (for (
    (recapItem, recapItemIndex) <- recap.recap_items.zipWithIndex;
    (invoiceItem, invoiceItemIndex) <- recapItem.invoice_items.zipWithIndex
  ) yield {
    s"recap_item[$recapItemIndex]invoiceItem[$invoiceItemIndex]" -> Map("id" -> s"$invoiceItem.id", "qty" -> s"$invoiceItem.qty", "sur_key" -> s"$invoiceItem.sur_key")
  }).toMap
```